# Cannot hear audio from other side of phonecalls or voicemails

Tags: audio, hardware

When I make a phone call (this includes to voicemail), I cannot hear the other party and the other party cannot hear me.

The problem is **isolated to calling**. When I'm having this problem (or more precisely, when I can replicate this problem), the following behavior is consistent:

- entering numbers with the dialpad produces the usual audible beep,
- the Sound Recorder app on my phone works fine,
- any apps that use the speakers work fine (e.g. Apollo, ES File Explorer audio service).

Rebooting my phone **temporarily** resolves the problem, which seems to recur an indefinite number of hours following a reboot. I have been unable to identify any specific app or service which causes this problem.

(Unrelated to the problem, but still relevant - CM hangs when I attempt to boot into safe mode, which is only resolveable by popping the battery and booting back up normally, at which point all configured widgets sans lock-screen Torch have been removed - these reboots also fix the problem - so tl;dr: being unable to boot into safe mode, I am unable to determine whether a particular third-party app/service is the cause of this problem).

I have a T-Mobile SII (Hercules SGH-T989) running CM 10.2.0-hercules (corresponds to Android 4.3.1, baseband version T989UVMC6 - I assume this is the radio). I have no call recording apps - the closest thing I have is the Dialer app, which (it seems) does not handle any calling, and simply hooks into the stock Phone app to make calls.

This began a number of months after I upgraded to CM 10.2.0-hercules from 10.0, so I highly doubt that CM is the problem here.

Comment: lots of people who plopped in new "other" firmware onto a phone lost the ability to make a call (couldn't hear and/or be heard).  Myself I could not believe they would continue trying it after that. "the only thing wrong is it isnt a phone anymore. :-) So while you are sure it is not that, you still have to go back to see :-(

Comment: Unless someone built a time bomb into CM 10.2.0, I seriously doubt that's what broke my phone, since my phone worked for a solid two months after the upgrade.